# Is System.Data.SQLite is the dll for using SQLite in Compact framework?

Tags: compact-framework

Is System.Data.SqlLite is the dll for using SQLLite in Compact framework

Comment: Are you talking about [this project](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is support for the .NET Compact Framework.